# Deserialise getAccountInfo data from Rust rpcclient for a PDA from drift protocol

Tags: rust, pda, program, deserialization

Basically I have the following code in devnet. I want to call getAccountInfo to get some account information.
I have a PDA: `JD71QyQpAJvoyq4p6mfwyaw4rY9qaDLk4CQpHeuPSpEK` created by the programId: `dRiftyHA39MWEi3m9aunc5MzRF1JYuBsbn6VPcn33UH`.

```
use solana_client::{rpc_client::RpcClient, rpc_config::RpcAccountInfoConfig};
use solana_sdk::{pubkey::Pubkey};

let rpc_client = RpcClient::new("https://api.devnet.solana.com".to_string());
let account_pubkey = Pubkey::from_str("JD71QyQpAJvoyq4p6mfwyaw4rY9qaDLk4CQpHeuPSpEK").unwrap();
let program_id = Pubkey::from_str("dRiftyHA39MWEi3m9aunc5MzRF1JYuBsbn6VPcn33UH").unwrap();
let config = RpcAccountInfoConfig {
        encoding: Some(UiAccountEncoding::Base64), 
        ..Default::default()
    };
let account = rpc_client.get_account_with_config(&account_pubkey, config).unwrap();
```

However, when I want to deserialise the data in account, which is Vec of u8, into the data structure `User`:

```
    let data = account.value.unwrap().data;
    match User::try_from_slice(&data) {
        Ok(x) => println!("OK: {:?}", x),
        Err(x) => println!("ERR: {:?}", x)
    }
```

I get error: `ERR: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "Unexpected variant index: 154" }`.

`User` is a struct copied from the source code of drift protocol-v2 from here [line 57]:
https://github.com/drift-labs/protocol-v2/blob/master/programs/drift/src/state/user.rs

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: what trait is the `try_from_slice` method from?

Comment: when we derive `BorshDerialize` on the struct User: `#[derive(Clone, Copy, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Debug, Eq)]`, we can call `try_from_slice`. https://docs.rs/borsh/latest/borsh/de/trait.BorshDeserialize.html, here is the `BorshDerialize` trait

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `User` struct isn't serialized with Borsh on the drift side, hence deserialization that way will fail. It's a zero-copy account instead. Try using anchor's [AccountLoader](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/account_loader/struct.AccountLoader.html) to deserialize accounts like this.

An `AccountLoader` can be created from a `AccountInfo` with `AccountLoader::try_from` and should provide the functionality you need for deserialization.

Comment: i added BorshDeserialize when I define the struct by this: `#[derive(Clone, Copy, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Debug, Eq)]`. It still cannot deserialise the data to the `User` struct..

Comment: You can't use borsh here because drift does not serialize the `User` account with borsh. Import the type directly from the drift library and access the underlying `User` object with `AccountLoader::load` after using `AccountLoader::try_from` to convert the `AccountInfo` gotten from `get_account_with_config` into an AccountLoader. 


As I mentioned earlier, borsh deserialization will not work.